# Proof + \mathaccent error

Tags: math-mode, errors, accents

I'm getting an error: "Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode" for the following code. I'm guessing it is a problem with `$Vˆ{\infty}$`, but I'm not really sure why it is wrong since it is in `$`.

```
\begin{proof}
(4) can be written component-wise for all $t$ 
as $v=Qv$, where $Q$ is the operator 
on $Vˆ{\infty}$ defined on the R.H.S of (4). 
\end{proof}
```

Comment: Are you using some strange document class or package?

Comment: @Mark - The OP is using a non-ASCII character (`ˆ`) instead of `^`.

Comment: wow; I'd have never caught that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a non-ASCII character, `ˆ`, instead of `^` as the superscript initiator. The character `ˆ` can also be inputted as `\textasciicircum`. That might be OK in text mode (as long as utf8 input encoding is used), but it doesn't work in math mode.

The upshot: Use only `^` in math mode.

An MWE (mininum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
$Vˆ{\infty}$ vs.\ $V^{\infty}$
\end{document}
```

The full set of warning messages actually is:

> ```
> LaTeX Warning: Command \textasciicircum invalid in math mode on input line 4.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Command \^ invalid in math mode on input line 4.
>
> ! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
>
> \add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
>
>                                                  #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
>
> l.4 $Vˆ
>
>         {\infty}$ vs.\ $V^{\infty}$
>
> ?
> ```

TeX's error and warning messages are famously terse (and sometimes nearly impenetrable). The key is to look for the *first* error or warning message, which in the present case is "LaTeX Warning: Command `\textasciicircum` invalid in math mode". This might have tipped you off; however, it may not have been obvious [!] that `ˆ` may also be entered as `\textasciicircum`.